# Json.net Deserialization not deserializing all properties

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm encountering a strange issue where when I serialize a class of mine using JsonConvert.SerializeObject (part of Json.Net for Unity), Deserializing, based on output, seems to skip some properties. For instance, this code:

```
JSonModifier healthMod = new JSonModifier("PlayerMain", "Health", "BaseAdd", 1f);
JSonModifierSkill jMod = new JSonModifierSkill(healthMod, "Staunch Warrior", 5, new string[0], new string[0]);  

Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jMod));
File.WriteAllText(jsonLocation, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jMod));
Debug.Log(File.ReadAllText(jsonLocation));  

JSonModifierSkill swJmod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSonModifierSkill>(File.ReadAllText(jsonLocation));
swJmod.Print();
ModifierSkill StaunchWarrior = swJmod.GetModifierSkill();
Debug.Log(StaunchWarrior.skillName + " " + StaunchWarrior.MaxLevel + " " + StaunchWarrior.skillModifier.valueType + " " + StaunchWarrior.locked + " " );
```

yields the following output:
{"skillName":"Staunch Warrior","MaxLevel":5,"statRequirements":[],"skillPrerequisites":     [],"modifier":{"type":"PlayerMain","valueType":"Health","ModEffect":"BaseAdd","value":1.0}}

{"skillName":"Staunch Warrior","MaxLevel":5,"statRequirements":[],"skillPrerequisites":[],"modifier":{"type":"PlayerMain","valueType":"Health","ModEffect":"BaseAdd","value":1.0}}
PlayerMain Health BaseAdd 1
5 System.String[]
5 baseAdd False
and here are the relevant classes:

```
class JSonModifier
{
    public string type;
    public string valueType;
    public string ModEffect;
    public float value;

    public JSonModifier(string _type, string _valueType, string _modEffect, float _value){
        type = _type;
        valueType = _valueType;
        ModEffect = _modEffect;
        value = _value;
    }
    public void Print(){
        Debug.Log(type + " " + valueType + " " + ModEffect + " " + value);
    }

    public Modifier GetModifier(){
        ModifierType  modType;
        ModifierValueType  modValType;
        PlayerMainModEffect  modEffect;

        Enum.TryParse(type, out modType);
        Enum.TryParse(valueType, out modValType);
        Enum.TryParse(ModEffect, out modEffect);
        return new Modifier(modType, modEffect, modValType, value);
    }
}
class JSonModifierSkill
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
     public  string skillName{get;}
     [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public int MaxLevel{get;protected set;}
    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public String[] statRequirements;
    [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
    public String[] skillPrerequisites {get;}
    [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
    public JSonModifier modifier;

    public JSonModifierSkill(JSonModifier _modifier, string _skillName, int __maxLevel, String[] statReq, String[] skillReq){
        modifier = _modifier;
        skillName = _skillName;
        MaxLevel = __maxLevel;
        statRequirements = statReq;
        skillPrerequisites = skillReq;
    }
    public void Print(){
        modifier.Print();
        Debug.Log(skillName + " " + MaxLevel + " " + statRequirements + " " + skillPrerequisites);
    }

    public ModifierSkill GetModifierSkill(){
        Modifier  mod = new Modifier(ModifierType.PlayerMain, PlayerMainModEffect.Health, ModifierValueType.baseAdd, 1f);
        //modifier.Print();

        //mod = modifier.GetModifier();
        return new ModifierSkill(skillName, MaxLevel, mod);
    }
```

I'm really stumped as the JSonModifier, statRequirements, and MaxLevel properties seem to be getting deserialized fine, and I'm not getting any errors, but skillName and skillPrerequisistes disappear?
Hoping someone can show me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out you need a setter to set the value of a property, who knew? ;)

Comment: For the data you are using you could simply use the built-in `JsonUtility` .. I would just make sure to make the classes `[Serializable]` and use fields instead of properties. If you then want read-only access do `[SerializeField] private string someField; public string SomeField => someField;` ;)

Comment: @derHugo I would recommend using the free Json.Net extension from the marketplace, the built in Unity Json is very lackluster (essentially can only handle primitives iirc). It was giving me a ton of problems, at least. And thanks for the tip!

Comment: I mentioned it because you **are** only using basic types within your classes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need a setter to set the value of a property, who knew? ;)